# use of class template requires template argument list c++ visual studios

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am currently using a class template for my linked list. I've defined it before the class as I was implementing it:

```
template <class ItemT>
struct Node {
    int len;
    Node* next;
    ItemT arr[ARRAY_SIZE];
}
```

However, when I run my code, I get an error in my class, specifically within private:

```
private:
        Node* head; // listData
        Node* currentPos; // tail
        int listLen;
        
};
```

It throws this error at me for
'''
Node * head;
'''
:
Error   C2955   'Node': use of class template requires template argument listList

**FIXED** (thanks to @Retired Ninja)
All I needed to do was:

```
private:
        Node*<Item T> head; // listData
        Node* <Item T> currentPos; // tail
        int listLen;
        
};
```

Comment: `Node<ItemT>*` inside the class. Same concept as `std::vector<int>`, etc.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Wow! Yes! Thank you sooooo much!

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you could write them as answer and mark them. This will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: @BarrnetChou hey! Sorry, I'm fairly new. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You could organize the method, write it in as answer, and mark it yourself.